# If $n$ is an even natural number then $2^{n-1}$ is divisible for $2^{\varphi(n)}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

If $n$ is an even natural number ($n \neq 0$) then is $2^{n-1}$ divisible by $2^{\varphi (n)}$?

Since $n$ is an even number then $n-1$ is an odd number. Hence, $(2,n)=1$. By Euler's theorem, $2^{\varphi (n-1)} - 1$ is divisible for $n-1$.

But I don't know what I should do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follows immediately by $\,n>1\Rightarrow\,\phi(n) \le n-\color{#c00}1\,$ since there is at least $\color{#c00}1$ one natural $<n$ not coprime to $n,\,$ namely $0.\,$ This is proved (in passing) here in many places, e.g. Andre's answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n>1$, $\varphi(n)\leqslant n-1$, and therefore $2^{\varphi(n)}\mid2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I don't understand why $2^{\varphi(n)} | 2^{n-1}$? May you explain it more precisely to me?

Comment: @FactorY If $a \leq b$ then $2^a\mid 2^b.$ Specifically, $2^b = 2^a \times 2^{b-a},$ where $2^{b-a}$ is an integer because $b-a\geq 0.$